# Babel-Standalone Error : Inline Babel script: Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled (14:1):

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, decorator, babeljs, es6-class

```js
// REF : https://jsfiddle.net/happyrupesh/j0v2c1r4/1/

function  newConstructor( HumanClass ) {
    // newConstructorFunc will modify or overwrite the HumanClass contructor function
    var  newConstructorFunc  =  function(firstName, lastName, age) {
        this.firstName  =  firstName
        this.lastName  =  lastName
        this.age  =  age
    }

    return  newConstructorFunc
} 


@newConstructor
class  Human {
    constructor( firstName, lastName ) {
        this.firstName  =  firstName;
        this.lastName  =  lastName;
    }
}


// Though Human class constructor function takes only two parameters, but due to 
// newConstructor now Human class can accept 3 parameters
var  person1  =  new  Human("Virat", "Kohli", 31);
console.log( person1 );

// Displays the modified constructor function
console.log( Human.prototype.constructor );
console.log(person1.__proto__.constructor);
```

I need guidance on using some plugins with [Babel Standalone](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone) version. As I have created simple code editor/code playground like JsFiddle to run and execute some code in the browser like ES6 examples, React, RxJs etc..

As this is not full stack editor. I am using **[Babel Standalone 7.7](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone)** version, now I am trying to run one ES6 @decorator example in that editor, but getting following error. I tried to search the solution over internet but didn't get any answer with proper example.

**`Uncaught SyntaxError: /Inline Babel script: Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled (14:1):`**

[image]

I had found one example of using Presets and Plugins with Babel Standalone : https://jsfiddle.net/0n8w6zh9/

But not sure how to use @decorator plugin with it.

**Below is the simplified code of my editor:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Code Editor</title>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.7.7/babel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/preset-env-standalone@7.7.3/babel-preset-env.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators@7.7.4/lib/index.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script id="require_method" type="text/javascript">
        function require(module) {
            if (module === "react") return React;
            if (module === "react-dom") return ReactDOM;
            if (module === "react-router-dom") return ReactRouterDOM;
            if (module === "rxjs") return rxjs; // RxJS 5.x
            if (module === "RxJs") return Rx;   // RxJS 6.x
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        // https://jsfiddle.net/0n8w6zh9/
        Babel.registerPreset("my-preset", {
            presets: [
                [Babel.availablePresets["es2015"], { "modules": false }]
            ],
            plugins: [
                [
                    Babel.availablePlugins["babel-preset-env"]
                ]
            ],
            moduleId: "main"
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- JavaScript Code -->
    <script type="text/babel" data-presets="my-preset">
// code which I want to compile and run using Babel-standalone

        function newConstructor(HumanClass) {
            // newConstructorFunc will modify or overwrite the HumanClass contructor function
            var newConstructorFunc = function (firstName, lastName, age) {
                this.firstName = firstName
                this.lastName = lastName
                this.age = age
            }

            return newConstructorFunc
        }

        @newConstructor
        class Human {
            constructor(firstName, lastName) {
                this.firstName = firstName;
                this.lastName = lastName;
            }
        }

        // Though Human class constructor function takes only two parameters, but due to
        // newConstructor now Human class can accept 3 parameters
        var person1 = new Human("Virat", "Kohli", 31);
        console.log(person1);

        // Displays the modified constructor function
        console.log(Human.prototype.constructor);
        console.log(person1.__proto__.constructor);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

> As the same @decorator example is working in JsFiddle when we select "Babel + JSX" option : https://jsfiddle.net/happyrupesh/j0v2c1r4/1/

[image]

Not sure what I am doing wrong or what is missing in my code.
Please guide on using @decorator functions inside browser using Babel Standalone.

Thanks,

Jignesh Raval

**Working Solution:**
I have added code snippet also.

```
<script class="static-script babel-standalone" src="https://fiddle.jshell.net/js/babel/babel.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/jsx" data-presets="es2017,react,stage-0" data-plugins="transform-decorators-legacy">

    // code which I want to compile and run using Babel-standalone
    console.log('Babel ===', Babel);

    function newConstructor(HumanClass) {
        // newConstructorFunc will modify or overwrite the HumanClass contructor function
        var newConstructorFunc = function (firstName, lastName, age) {
            this.firstName = firstName
            this.lastName = lastName
            this.age = age
        }

        return newConstructorFunc
    }

    @newConstructor
    class Human {
        constructor(firstName, lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    }

    // Though Human class constructor function takes only two parameters, but due to
    // newConstructor now Human class can accept 3 parameters
    var person1 = new Human("Virat", "Kohli", 31);
    console.log(person1);

    // Displays the modified constructor function
    console.log(Human.prototype.constructor);
    console.log(person1.__proto__.constructor);
</script>
```

```html
<script class="static-script babel-standalone" src="https://fiddle.jshell.net/js/babel/babel.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
        
<script type="text/jsx" data-presets="es2017,react,stage-0" data-plugins="transform-decorators-legacy">

    // code which I want to compile and run using Babel-standalone
    console.log('Babel ===', Babel);

    function newConstructor(HumanClass) {
        // newConstructorFunc will modify or overwrite the HumanClass contructor function
        var newConstructorFunc = function (firstName, lastName, age) {
            this.firstName = firstName
            this.lastName = lastName
            this.age = age
        }

        return newConstructorFunc
    }

    @newConstructor
    class Human {
        constructor(firstName, lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    }

    // Though Human class constructor function takes only two parameters, but due to
    // newConstructor now Human class can accept 3 parameters
    var person1 = new Human("Virat", "Kohli", 31);
    console.log(person1);

    // Displays the modified constructor function
    console.log(Human.prototype.constructor);
    console.log(person1.__proto__.constructor);
</script>
```

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to this? I have the same issue

Comment: Hi @cbutler, I have added working example for the same and it is working with Babel version: "6.24.0"

Comment: Thanks @Jignesh Ravel but I got this working by updating my version of babel and changing some settings. I should have updated my comment! I can upload code if anyone needs.

Comment: Thanks @cbutler.
Yes, please share your Babel settings, Babel Version and code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same code with Babel standalone version 7.12.9, still getting below error. I tried few options but was not able to make it work. If any one can guide how to make it work. but it worked properly with Babel version 6.x.

`babel-standalone@7.12.9.js:65221 Uncaught Error: [BABEL] /Inline Babel script: The decorators plugin requires a 'decoratorsBeforeExport' option, whose value must be a boolean. If you want to use the legacy decorators semantics, you can set the 'legacy: true' option. (While processing: "base$0$0")`

Reference link : https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone

```
<script>
// Define a preset
Babel.registerPreset("env-plus", {
  presets: [
    [Babel.availablePresets["env"], { "loose": true }]
  ],
  plugins: [
    [
      Babel.availablePlugins["proposal-decorators"], { decoratorsBeforeExport: true }
    ]
  ],
});
</script>

<script type="text/babel" data-presets="env-plus"></script>
```

**Then I tried Babel version 6.26.0, and it worked properly. Please refer live example added here.**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>

<script type="text/jsx" data-presets="es2017,react,stage-0" data-plugins="transform-decorators-legacy">
    // code which I want to compile and run using Babel-standalone
    console.log('Babel ===', Babel);

    function newConstructor(HumanClass) {
        // newConstructorFunc will modify or overwrite the HumanClass contructor function
        var newConstructorFunc = function (firstName, lastName, age) {
            this.firstName = firstName
            this.lastName = lastName
            this.age = age
        }

        return newConstructorFunc
    }

    @newConstructor
    class Human {
        constructor(firstName, lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    }

    // Though Human class constructor function takes only two parameters, but due to
    // newConstructor now Human class can accept 3 parameters
    var person1 = new Human("Virat", "Kohli", 31);
    console.log(person1);

    // Displays the modified constructor function
    console.log(Human.prototype.constructor);
    console.log(person1.__proto__.constructor);
</script>
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Thanks,
Jignesh Raval